# Simple join makes MySQL/MariaDB COUNT(*) rows very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm joining two tables and counting returned rows with simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(parc2.id) 
FROM SHIP__shipments AS ship 
JOIN SHIP__shipments_parcels AS parc2 ON ship.shipmentId = parc2.shipmentId
```

It takes approx. 2 seconds to provide result, which is around 800k rows. Primary table has cca. 700k rows, joined table has cca. 800k rows.

Both tables have indexes and all that stuff. Join without counting is very fast, cca. 0.005s. 
Counting just one table is also very fast, something like 0.01s.
Once counting and join is in the same query, we are dropping to 2s with 99% of time in "sending data" by profiler.

Output from explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  ship    index   PRIMARY senderId    4   NULL    738700  Using index 
1   SIMPLE  parc2   ref shippmentId,shipmentId  shippmentId 4   ship.shipmentId 1   Using index
```

I did tons of tries during testing. Using for example combined keys, using count(*), forcing index to use.. also more exotic ways like using subqueries, etc. Nothing really helps, it's always that slow.

Tables:

```
   CREATE TABLE `SHIP__shipments` (
  `shipmentId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'generated ID',
  `externalId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'spedition number',
  `senderId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK - sender address',
  `recipientId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fk - recipient address',
  `customerId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK - custromer',
  `packageCount` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'number of parcels',
  `shipmentPickupDate` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'when to pickup shipent',
  `shipmenmtDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'free description',
  `codAmount` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'COD to take',
  `codReference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'customer''s COD refference',
  `codCurrencyCode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FK - currency',
  `codConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'COD confirmed by spedition',
  `codSent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'COD paid to customer? 1/0',
  `trackingCountryCode` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK - country of shippment tracking',
  `subscriptionDate` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'when to enter to the sped. system',
  `speditionCode` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK - spedition',
  `shipmentType` enum('DIRECT','WAREHOUSE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'WAREHOUSE' COMMENT 'internal OLZA flag',
  `weight` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'sum weight of parcells',
  `billingPrice` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'stored price of delivery',
  `billingCurrencyCode` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'storred currency of delivery price',
  `invoiceCreated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'invoicing has been done? 1/0',
  `invoicingDate` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'date of creating invoice',
  `pickupPlaceId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'pickup place ID, if applicable for shipment',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastCheckDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'last date of status check'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='shippment details';

ALTER TABLE `SHIP__shipments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`shipmentId`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `senderId` (`senderId`) USING BTREE,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `externalId` (`externalId`,`trackingCountryCode`,`speditionCode`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `recipientId_2` (`recipientId`),
  ADD KEY `recipientId` (`recipientId`),
  ADD KEY `customerId` (`customerId`),
  ADD KEY `codCurrencyCode` (`codCurrencyCode`),
  ADD KEY `trackingCountryCode` (`trackingCountryCode`),
  ADD KEY `speditionCode` (`speditionCode`);

ALTER TABLE `SHIP__shipments`
  MODIFY `shipmentId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'generated ID';


ALTER TABLE `SHIP__shipments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`recipientId`) REFERENCES `SHIP__recipient_list` (`recipientId`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`customerId`) REFERENCES `CUST__customer_list` (`customerId`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`codCurrencyCode`) REFERENCES `SYS__currencies` (`code`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`trackingCountryCode`) REFERENCES `SYS__countries` (`code`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`speditionCode`) REFERENCES `SYS__speditions` (`code`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`senderId`) REFERENCES `SHIP__sender_list` (`senderId`);

CREATE TABLE `SHIP__shipments_parcels` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'generated ID',
  `shipmentId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK - shippment',
  `externalNumber` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'number from spedition',
  `externalBarcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Barcode ID - external reference',
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FK - current status',
  `weigth` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'weight of parcel',
  `weightConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'provided weight has been confirmed/updated by measuring',
  `parcelType` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='data and relations between shippment and it''s parcels';

ALTER TABLE `SHIP__shipments_parcels`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `shippmentId` (`shipmentId`,`status`),
  ADD KEY `status` (`status`),
  ADD KEY `parcelType` (`parcelType`),
  ADD KEY `externalBarcode` (`externalBarcode`),
  ADD KEY `weightConfirmed` (`weightConfirmed`),
  ADD KEY `externalNumber` (`externalNumber`),
  ADD KEY `shipmentId` (`shipmentId`);


ALTER TABLE `SHIP__shipments_parcels`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'generated ID';

ALTER TABLE `SHIP__shipments_parcels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_parcels_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `SHIP__statuses` (`statusCode`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_parcels_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`shipmentId`) REFERENCES `SHIP__shipments` (`shipmentId`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SHIP__shipments_parcels_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`parcelType`) REFERENCES `SHIP__parcel_types` (`parcelType`);
```

Server is running on SSD disks and we are not talking about a lot of data here.
Am I missing something here? Or 2 seconds is real time of row counting?

Can I have count result in "normal" time like 0.01s?

We are running MariaDB 10.

Comment: Why is there `senderid` in the explain? It doesn't occur anywhere in your query. Are you sure those two are related? Anyway, just a guess, try to use `count(*)` rather than `count(parc2.id)`. `id` is declared `NOT NULL` and you're using an inner join, so `id` cannot be `NULL` whatsoever. Maybe the optimizer doesn't get that.

Comment: "Join without counting is very fast..." -- I doubt 700k rows joined with 800k rows takes 20 ms or less. Maybe your query tool is limiting the rows to 1000 or so, so you don't get them all at once, and that's why it seems very fast. However, when counting, the engine needs to go through ALL rows for real; it takes 2 s (something I find decent).

Comment: Try reversing the two tables and doing `select straight_join ...`.  Also try adding `use index ()` before `JOIN`, both with your current query and with the reversed query.  But likely there is not much you can do

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I already tried all your suggestions before posting question here. Anyway, it finally seems, that it's real DB processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis**

Let's dissect some columns and the `EXPLAIN`:

```
`shipmentId` int(11)  (*3)  NOT NULL COMMENT 'generated ID',
`senderId`   int(11)  (*3)  NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK - sender address',


1   SIMPLE  ship    index   PRIMARY 
  senderId (*2)    4   NULL        738700  Using index (*1)
1   SIMPLE  parc2   ref shippmentId,shipmentId
  shippmentId (*4) 4   ship.shipmentId 1   Using index (*1) 

SELECT ... count(parc2.id)  (*5)  ...  STRAIGHT_JOIN (*6)  ...
```

Notes:

*1 -- Both are `Using index`; this is likely to help a lot.
*2 -- `INDEX(senderId)` is probably the "smallest" index.  Note that you are using InnoDB.  The PK is "clustered" with the data, so it is not "small".  Every secondary index has the PK implicitly tacked on, so that is effectively `(senderId, shipmentId)`.  This explains why the Optimizer mysteriously picked `INDEX(senderId)`.
*3 -- `INT` takes 4 bytes, allowing numbers up to +/- 2 billion.  Do you expect to have that many senders and shipments?  Shrinking the datatype (and making it `UNSIGNED` will save some space and I/O, and therefore *may* speed things up a little.
*4 -- `INDEX(shipmentId)` is actually like `INDEX(shipmentId, id)`, again 2 INTs.
*5 -- `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NOT NULL`.  This is *probably* unnecessary in your application.  Change to `COUNT(*)` unless you do need the null check.  (The performance difference will be minor.)
*6 -- It probably does not matter which table it picks first, except perhaps for what indexes are available.  Hence, `STRAIGHT_JOIN` did not help.

Now let's discuss how the `JOIN` works.  Virtually all `JOINs` in MySQL are "NLJ" (Nested Loop Join).  This is where the code walks through one of the tables (actually just an index for one table), then reaches into the other table (also, just into an index) for each row found.

To do a `COUNT(*)` it only needs to check for the existence of the row.

So, it walked through the 2-column `INDEX(senderId, shipmentId)` to find a list of all `shipmentIds` in the first table.  It did not waste time sorting or dedupping that list.  And, since `shipmentId` is the PK, (hence `UNIQUE`), there won't be any dups.

For each `shipmentId`, it then looked up all the rows in the second table.  That was efficient to do because of `INDEX(shipmentId, id)`.

**I/O (or not)**

Let's digress into another issue.  Was there any I/O?  Were all those rows of those two indexes fully cached in RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

The way InnoDB fetches a row (from a table or from an index) is to first check to see if it is in the "buffer pool".  If it is not there, then it must bump something out of the buffer pool and read the desired 16KB block into the buffer pool.

At one extreme, nothing is in the buffer pool and all the blocks must be read from disk.  At the other extreme, all are cached, and no I/O is needed.  Since you tried all sorts of things, I assume that all the relevant blocks (those two indexes) were in RAM.

2 INTs * (800K + 700K rows) + some overhead = maybe 50MB.  Assuming `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is more than that, and no swapping occurred, then it is reasonable for there to be no I/O.

So, how long should it take to touch 1.5M rows that are fully cached, in a `JOIN`?  Alas, 2 seconds seems reasonable.

**User expectations**

It is rare to need an *exact, up-to-the-second* count that is in the millions.  Rethink the User requirement.  Or we can discuss ways to pre-compute the value.  Or dead-reckon it.

**Side notes**

(These do not impact the question at hand.)

- Don't blindly use `255` for all strings.
- `UNIQUE(x)` is an `INDEX`, so don't also have `INDEX(x)`.
- Having more than 2 `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` indexes is usually a design error in the schema.
- Some columns could (should?) be normalized.  Example: `parcelType`?
- Don't use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for monetary values; use `DECIMAL`.  (`weight` could be floating.)

Comment: Many thanks for these details. You replied to all my questions about how this is processed in within DB engine. Seems, that we need to change approach a bit, as we can't make it much faster as it is right now. At least, any "big" SQL mistake is off the table now.